# Subclassing UIGestureRecognizer and returning custom UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I've created my own `UIView` subclass with a new prototype. That no problem, but when I'm trying to get my state of the **subclassed UIView** it goes wrong.

I have an GestureRecognizer on my `UIView` and with subclassing and using the new variable it is not recognized because the `UIGestureRecognizers` view variable returns an UIView.

So I subclassed the `UIGestureRecognizer` but this does not work. I'm getting an error:

```
-[BannerView countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xe872480
```

And here is my code in the subclassed `UIGestureRecognizers`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "BannerView.h"

@interface GestureReco : UIGestureRecognizer

@property (nonatomic,readonly) BannerView *view;

@end
```

How can I solve this problem or do I need to handle this on an other way that the UIGestureRecognizer knows that I've subclassed the UIView and want to GET my variable from my own UIView class.

Comment: It seems you do not really know what a `UIView` and what a `UIGestureRecognizer` is. Whare are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @duci9y so I've subclassed UIView to add an enum state for knowing more stuff about my UIView for my game. In my tap recognizer I'm checking for my subclassed UIViews enum. But this is not possible because the UIGestureRecognizer returns an UIView and not my UIView Subclass.

Comment: It doesn't seem like you need the UIGestureRecognizer subclass.  The gesture recognizer's `view` property is typed as `UIView` which means a "plain" UIView or a UIView subclass.  So you probably just need to cast it to your UIView subclass so the compiler will let you get at your enum states easily.  May want to check that the view is actually your UIView subclass using isKindOfClass before casting and using it like your class.  Post the tap recognizer method that you tried.

Comment: Oh yeah, it worked with casting it to my subclass. First it didn't work with dot notation. But now on the normal objective-c way it worked! Yay thanks